# How can I, if possible, create a command whose output is dependent on an argument/parameter for language switching?

Tags: macros, languages, robust-commands

## Question

I would like the ability to work with macros in multilingual (`xelatex`) documents.

### Example Situation

I have a large document in 8 languages that share a common preamble. I decide there is some section of the document that is not only common to all documents, but it also must be frequently changed. I want to put that information in a preamble for easy access. I decide to create a command that takes iso 639.1 codes (en, de, da, nl, el) as its parameter for determining which snippet of text and corresponding language should be inserted (default parameter being en for English, because maybe I have 5 other languages, but parts of them use English)

### Sample Command

```
\disclaimer[da]{} % This would insert a disclaimer in Danish
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand correctly.

Loading `xstring` you can define something like

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\disclaimer}[1]{%
    \IfEq{#1}{en}{English disclaimer}{}%
    \IfEq{#1}{de}{German disclaimer}{}%
    \IfEq{#1}{da}{Danish disclaimer}{}%
}
```

and use it as in the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xstring}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\disclaimer}[1]{%
    \IfEq{#1}{en}{English disclaimer}{}%
    \IfEq{#1}{de}{German disclaimer}{}%
    \IfEq{#1}{da}{Danish disclaimer}{}%
}

\begin{document}

\disclaimer{en}

\disclaimer{de}

\disclaimer{da}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: +1 Why did you add `polyglossia`? I am trying to avoid that package (including Babel). I do use `fontspec` for utf8 support. But seems like this could work. English is not the default language in your example, however (although that is not a deal-breaker)

Comment: @macmadness86 Deleted `polyglossia`. It's not needed at all.